# java - Синхронизация потоков

Tags: java, синхронизация

Имеются два блока кода назовем их **А и В**. Они в различных классах и пакетах кода и в принципе никак не взаимосвязаны. Каждый из них вызывается только из своего потока. Но они не должны быть исполнены в одно и тоже время. При этом каждый из блоков выполнятся много раз за секунду из за чего они крайне важны в плане быстродействие программы. И если **А** уже выполнятся **B** может пропустить свою итерацию и продолжит исполнение своего потока, но наоборот **А** придется ждать завершения **B**. Также **A** имеет приоритет над **B** и в случае одновременного запроса на выполнение предпочтение отдается **А**. Как это сделать учитывая важность для быстродействия программы? Я так понимаю надо использовать что то из пакета java.util.concurrent?

Comment: Executor попробуйте: https://tproger.ru/translations/java8-concurrency-tutorial-1/

Comment: "если А уже выполнятся B может пропустить свою итерацию", что это означает? если А и B вызываются одинаково много, то должно выполняться только А,а вызовы B должны какое-то время ждать, а затем пропускаться?

Comment: Попробуйте применить Lock. У ReentrantLock есть два метода: lock() - когда поток будет ждать снятия блокировки, и tryLock() - когда поток попробует получить блокировку, но не прекратит исполнение если она не получена, зато вернет состояние блокировки true или false, с помощью чего можно настроить логику работы.

Comment: @Mark Да вроде как это то что мне нужно. Но все же для уточнение. ReentrantLock действует также как и ключевое слово synchronized. За тем отличием что в synchronized нету ничего близкого по функционалу к tryLock() и реализовать эту логику программы ванильным synchronized не получиться?

Comment: @Dines Хороший способ реализации trylock на syncronized мне неизвестен. В чисто научных целях можно в блоки кода A и В ввести явное присвоение общей для них переменной какого либо значения на входе и на выходе, например инкрементировать/декрементировать AtomicInteger, и сверяться с ней еще перед заходом в синхроблок.